Error: [NOT_FOUND]: Template not found for project number 1234512345 and namespace firebase-server
I am seeing this error when trying to use Firebase Remote Config in a Server Action of a NextJS app:

Error: [NOT_FOUND]: Template not found for project number 1234512345 and namespace firebase-server

My Firebase Remote Config setup works fine in the Flutter app connected to it but not in NextJS.

I discovered that you can have two separate remote config mappings in the Firebase console: one for the client, and one for the server.

My project only had data in the client section. After selecting the drop down next to the "Remote Config" title, selecting server, and adding values there, everything started working again.
